# JSON Query or JavaScriptSerializer for FullCalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

Using the fullcalendar JQuery Model,

Works perfectly if I manually enter the javascript objects:

```
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        editable: true,
        theme:true,
       events : [
    {
        title: 'Event1',
        start: '2014-03-12'
    },
    {
        title: 'Event2',
        start: '2014-03-1'
    }
    // etc...
        ],
```

But when I use a JSON or JavaScriptSerializer ashx handler, nothing shows on the calendar. Am I missing something? or have I made a stupid error:

Code from page calling JSON or JavaScript - I actually get objects back and can see them but not on calendar:

```
      events:
        {
            url: $("#ASHXHandlerTextBox").val(),
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                startdate: $("#StartDateTextBox").val(),
                calendar: $("#CalendarToUseTextBox").val(),
                userid: $("#UserIdTextBox").val()
            },
            error: function() {
                alert($("#ASHXHandlerTextBox").val());
            },
            success: function (data) {
                for (var key in data) {
                    if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                        alert(key + " -> " + data[key]);
                    }
                }
            },
            color: 'yellow',   // a non-ajax option
            textColor: 'black' // a non-ajax option
        }

    });
```

Code from "ashx JavaScriptSerializer"  file:

```
    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(new
        {
            items = new[] {
            new {title = "command" , start = "Wed, 12 Mar 2014 "}, 
            new {title = "command2" , start = "Thu, 13 Mar 2014 "}
        }
        }));
```

Code from ashx JSON Handler:

```
        context.Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
        {
            items = new[] {
            new {title = "command" , start = "2014-03-12"}, 
            new {title = "command2" , start = "2014-03-13"}
        }
        }));
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Fixed it, something really silly, I was using  context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";  instead of context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";